# Model companionship result for integral domains as axiomatized in signature with additive and multiplicative inverses

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, model-theory

Consider the theory of integral domains in signature $\{+,\cdot,-,0,1\}$ where $+,\cdot$ stand for addition and multiplication and $-$ for additive inverse. Then its model companion is the theory of algebraically closed fields. Now assume we add also a symbol ${}^{-1}$ for multiplicative inverse, and an axiom stating that the multiplicative inverse of a number is the correct one when the number has it, and is $0$ otherwise, i.e.:
$$
\forall x\,[\exists y\,(x\cdot y=1\wedge x^{-1}=y)\vee (\neg\exists y\,(x\cdot y=1)\wedge x^{-1}=0)]
$$
Does integral domains in signature $\{+,\cdot,-,{}^{-1},0,1\}$ has a model companion? Note that if it does, this model companion theory is not the theory of algebraically closed fields: $\mathbb{C}$ is a substructure of $\mathbb{C}[X]$ also according to this expanded signature, but not a $\Sigma_1$-substructure, as $X$ witnesses in $\mathbb{C}[X]$ the truth of the $\Sigma_1$-sentence $\exists y(y\neq 0\wedge y^{-1}=0)$, which is false in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Are you sure this is how you would want your symbol $(-)^{-1}$ to work? It would mean that $\mathbb{Z}$ is not a substructure of $\mathbb{C}$: for example $2^{-1} = 0$ in $\mathbb{Z}$. A perhaps better definition for $(-)^{-1}$ would be as a binary relation, which defines $x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}$ as a partial function (so $x^{-1}$ simply isn't defined if $x$ has no multiplicative inverse). I think that the model companion is then the algebraically closed fields again.

Comment: I'd really prefer to axiomatize multiplicative inverse by a unary operation rather than with a binary operation. I'm curious to understand what happens in this case because the axiomatization of this partial operation is given by a $\Pi_2$-sentence in integral domains, and by a $\Pi_1$-sentence in fields, and I would like to understand better whether this different syntactic complexity is really outlining the obstruction to get a model companionship result.

Comment: My proposal is not a binary _operation_, but a binary _relation_ that will then code a partial unary operation. This can still be done using a $\Pi_1$-sentence: $\forall xy(xy = 1 \leftrightarrow R(x, y))$, where $R$ is our binary relation. It then already follows that this relation is functional, that is $\forall xyz(R(x, y) \wedge R(x, z) \to y = z)$, however this is $\Pi_1$ anyway as you see so you could include it anyway.

Comment: In fact, related to your question about $\Pi_1$ versus $\Pi_2$ sentences there is the following fact. Let $T$ be a theory that can be formulated using $\Pi_2$-sentences. Let $T^{ec}$ be the set of all $\Pi_2$-sentences that are true in every e.c. model of $T$ and let $T^u$ be the set of all $\Pi_1$-consequences of $T$ (equivalently all $\Pi_1$-sentences true in every e.c. model of $T$). Then for any $T'$ in the same signature we have that $T$ and $T'$ have the same e.c. models iff $T^{ec} \models T'$ and $T' \models T^u$.

Comment: @curiousonmathematics The axiomatization you wrote is $\Pi_2$, but you can make it $\Pi_1$: $$\forall x\, (x\cdot x^{-1} = 1 \lor ((\forall y\, x\cdot y \neq 1)\land x^{-1} = 0).$$